# Need Sql query output like this format

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have one time sheet table when i fetch the records it will display like this for one week.

This record is from one week from June 10 to June 16

```
EmpId  Monday Tuesday Wednesday Thursday Friday Saturday Sunday    StartDate     EndDate
1      08:00   08:12    00:00     04:00   00:00   03:00   00:00   05/10/2013     05/16/2013
```

Need the output like this

```
Empid  Monday startdate   EndDate
1      08:00  05/10/2013 05/10/2013
1      08:12  05/11/2013 05/11/2013
1      04:00  05/13/2013 05/13/2013
1      03:00  05/15/2013 05/15/2013
```

Comment: How far have you gotten in a solution?  And please tag you question with the appropriate version of SQL Server.

Comment: The header for the second column is incorrect unless I'm reading your data wrong.  Shouldn't it be Hours, not Monday?

Answer (score 1):

This is basically an unpivot query.  Because of the time fields, this version chooses to do it explicitly (using `cross join` and `case`) rather than using `unpivot`:

```
select t.*
from (select h.empid,
             (case when n = 0 then Monday
                   when n = 1 then Tuesday
                   when n = 2 then Wednesday
                   when n = 3 then Thursday
                   when n = 4 then Friday
                   when n = 5 then Saturday
                   when n = 6 then Sunday
              end) as hours,
             (startdate + n) as StartDate,
             (startdate + n) as EndDate
      from hours h join
           (select 0 as n union all
            select 1 union all
            select 2 union all
            select 3 union all
            select 4 union all
            select 5 union all
            select 6
           ) n
     ) t
where hours > 0;
```

You can see the SQLFiddle [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7441c6/5).  And there is no problem running this on larger amounts of data.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you started:

```
declare @Hours as Table ( EmpId Int, Monday Time, Tuesday Time, Wednesday Time,
  Thursday Time, Friday Time, Saturday Time, Sunday Time, StartDate Date, EndDate Date );
insert into @Hours
  ( EmpId, Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday, StartDate, EndDate )
  values
  ( 1, '08:00', '08:12', '00:00', '04:00', '00:00', '03:00', '00:00', '20130510', '20130516' );
select * from @Hours;

with Week as (
  -- Build a table of all of the dates in the work week.
  select StartDate as WorkDate, EndDate
    from @Hours
  union all
  select DateAdd( day, 1, WorkDate ), EndDate
    from Week
    where WorkDate < EndDate )
  -- Output the result.
  select EmpId,
    case DatePart( weekday, W.WorkDate )
      when 1 then H.Monday
      when 2 then H.Tuesday
      when 3 then H.Wednesday
      when 4 then H.Thursday
      when 5 then H.Friday
      when 6 then H.Saturday
      when 7 then H.Sunday
      end as Hours,
    WorkDate as StartDate, WorkDate as EndDate,
    DatePart( weekday, W.WorkDate ) as DayOfWeek
    from Week as W inner join
      @Hours as H on H.StartDate <= W.WorkDate and W.WorkDate <= H.EndDate;

with Week as (
  -- Build a table of all of the dates in the work week.
  select StartDate as WorkDate, EndDate
    from @Hours
  union all
  select DateAdd( day, 1, WorkDate ), EndDate
    from Week
    where WorkDate < EndDate ),
  DaysHours as (
  -- Build a table of the hours assigned to each date.
  select EmpId,
    case DatePart( weekday, W.WorkDate )
      when 1 then H.Monday
      when 2 then H.Tuesday
      when 3 then H.Wednesday
      when 4 then H.Thursday
      when 5 then H.Friday
      when 6 then H.Saturday
      when 7 then H.Sunday
      end as Hours,
    WorkDate as StartDate, WorkDate as EndDate
    from Week as W inner join
      @Hours as H on H.StartDate <= W.WorkDate and W.WorkDate <= H.EndDate )
  -- Output the non-zero hours.
  select EmpId, Hours, StartDate, EndDate
    from DaysHours
    where Hours <> Cast( '00:00' as Time );
```

This works for a single row, but you will need to make some changes if your dataset grows.

Comment: Wow it great but value which hours have "00:00" not need to fetch the records....

Comment: `where Hours <> Cast( '00:00' as Time )` seems to filter out the zeros.  Answer updated.

Comment: @WebDeveloper - Strange.  I just copied the code from the answer and ran it again and it returns only the four rows with non-zero hours.

Comment: i have inserted the values from like this   ( 1, '00:00', '00:00', '02:00', '00:00', '02:00', '00:00', '00:00', '20130610', '20130616' ); then it should  show two records thats fine problem is 9 02:00 2013-06-11 00:00:00.000 2013-06-11 00:00:00.000
9 06:00 2013-06-13 00:00:00.000 2013-06-13 00:00:00.000 actually for wednesday only that means not '11' it should show '12' and friday it shows '13' it should be 14

Comment: @WebDeveloper - Some of us sleep when we aren't writing, and rewriting, code for free. I'll let you to take it from here.